# How to space plots in matplotlib equally without shrinking?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot 4 images in a single row. Below is my code.

```
plt.subplot(141)
plt.plot(np.arange(50, 450, 50), BNB_df['auc'], 'bo--',label="BNB-AUC")
plt.title('docs')
plt.subplot(142)
plt.plot(np.arange(50, 450, 50), BNB_df['accuracy'],'go-', label="BNB-Accuracy")
plt.subplot(143)
plt.plot(np.arange(50, 450, 50), LR_df['auc'], 'ro-',label="LR-AUC")
plt.subplot(144)
plt.plot(np.arange(50, 450, 50), LR_df['accuracy'],'go-', label="LR-Accuracy")
plt.show()
```

[image: resuting graph for above]

I don't know how to phrase my problem correctly. If I add this to my project report professor will not like it. How to make this graph wide and spaced equally in a single row?

Comment: Try plt.tight_layout() before plt.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(np.arange(50, 450, 50), BNB_df['auc'], 'bo-',label="BNB-AUC")
plt.title('BNB-AUC')
plt.xlabel("no of docs")
plt.ylabel("AUC")
plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(np.arange(50, 450, 50), BNB_df['accuracy'],'go-', label="BNB-Accuracy")
plt.title('BNB-Accuracy')
plt.xlabel("no of docs")
plt.ylabel("Accracy")
plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot(np.arange(50, 450, 50), LR_df['auc'], 'bo-',label="LR-AUC")
plt.title('LR-AUC')
plt.xlabel("no of docs")
plt.ylabel("AUC")
plt.subplot(224)
plt.plot(np.arange(50, 450, 50), LR_df['accuracy'],'go-', label="LR-Accuracy")
plt.title('LR-Accuracy')
plt.xlabel("no of docs")
plt.ylabel("Accracy")
```

## This makes better look

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]